# Get everything after and before certain character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got the following entry in my database:

```
images/test.jpg
```

I want to trim the entry so I get: `test`

So basically, I want everything after `/` and before `.`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there any specific reason not to do it in the client language (i.e. .NET, Java, PHP or whatever...)?

Comment: Yes. If it wasn`t I wouldn`t ask the question.

Comment: And would you be so kind to share it with us? Databases are for storing the data, not displaying it in any particular format. Your question may or may not be indicative of a deeper problem, and for us to be able to judge that, we need a reason.

Comment: Josien managed to answer just fine :)

Comment: Yes, he answered your question. That wasn't my point.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: or she :-)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you want to get this out of your table using SQL, take a look at the following functions that will help you: [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) and [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql). You can use those to trim your entries.

A possible query will look like this (where `col` is the name of the column that contains your image directories:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, LEN(SUBSTRING(col, 0, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('/', col))) + 1, 
    LEN(col) - LEN(SUBSTRING(col, 0, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('/', col))) - LEN(SUBSTRING(
    col, CHARINDEX ('.', col), LEN(col))));
```

Bit of an ugly beast. It also depends on the standard format of 'dir/name.ext'.

**Edit:**
This one (inspired by [praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1134928)) is more generic and deals with extensions of different length:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('/', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(LEFT(col, 
    CHARINDEX ('/', col))) - LEN(RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('.', col))) - 1);
```

Comment: The query however wont work if different extension (.jpeg,png,jpg) are inserted into the column .Never the less it works absolutely fine with the OP's sample data

Comment: @praveen: it works on extensions of different length - as long as they start with a dot.

Comment: Consider an input like 'images/test.jpeg .Your sql query retrieves est as the result

Answer (score 107):

use the following function

```
left(@test, charindex('/', @test) - 1)
```

Comment: While this does not answer the OPs 2 requirements, it is a nice CLEAN method of answering his 1st - and the more common request. (It is EXACTLY what I was looking for)

Comment: It fails if character is not presented there

Comment: LEFT(@test, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', @test)-1, -1), LEN(@test)));

Comment: What will be the option to pass TEXT datatype in left() instead of VARCHAR?

Answer (score 38):

Before

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ParentBGBU,0,CHARINDEX('/',ParentBGBU,0)) FROM dbo.tblHCMMaster;
```

After

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ParentBGBU,CHARINDEX('-',ParentBGBU)+1,LEN(ParentBGBU)) FROM dbo.tblHCMMaster
```

Answer (score 14):

----select characters before / including /

```
select SUBSTRING ('abcde/wxyz',0,CHARINDEX('/','abcde/wxyz')+1)
```

--select characters after / including /

```
select SUBSTRING('abcde/wxyz',CHARINDEX('/','abcde/wxyz'),LEN('abcde/wxyz'))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 declare @T table
  (
  Col varchar(20)
  )



  insert into @T 
  Select 'images/test1.jpg'
  union all
  Select 'images/test2.png'
  union all
  Select 'images/test3.jpg'
  union all
  Select 'images/test4.jpeg'
  union all
  Select 'images/test5.jpeg'

 Select substring( LEFT(Col,charindex('.',Col)-1),charindex('/',Col)+1,len(LEFT(Col,charindex('.',Col)-1))-1 )
from @T
```

Answer (score 5):

I have made a method which is much more general  :

so :

```
DECLARE @a NVARCHAR(MAX)='images/test.jpg';


 --Touch here
DECLARE @keysValueToSearch NVARCHAR(4000) = '/'
DECLARE @untilThisCharAppears NVARCHAR(4000) = '.'
DECLARE @keysValueToSearchPattern NVARCHAR(4000) = '%' + @keysValueToSearch + '%'


 --Nothing to touch here     
SELECT SUBSTRING(
           @a,
           PATINDEX(@keysValueToSearchPattern, @a) + LEN(@keysValueToSearch),
           CHARINDEX(
               @untilThisCharAppears,
               @a,
               PATINDEX(@keysValueToSearchPattern, @a) + LEN(@keysValueToSearch)
           ) -(PATINDEX(@keysValueToSearchPattern, @a) + LEN(@keysValueToSearch))
       )
```

Comment: This is a good example and. really thank you for this.
If there's a plan to use this code in function or SP, I recommend checking if there are values in input string:
DECLARE FirstAppearanceIndex [int] = CHARINDEX(KeysValueToSearch, InputString);
 DECLARE SecondAppearanceIndex [int] = CHARINDEX(UntilThisCharAppears, InputString);

 IF (FirstAppearanceIndex <= 0 OR SecondAppearanceIndex <= 0 OR FirstAppearanceIndex > SecondAppearanceIndex)
  BEGIN
  RETURN '';
  END

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Substring('ravi1234@gmail.com', 1, ( Charindex('@', 'ravi1234@gmail.com')
                                            - 1 ))
       Before,
       RIGHT('ravi123@gmail.com', ( Charindex('@', 'ravi123@gmail.com') + 1 ))
       After
```

Answer (score 3):

I just did this in one of my reports and it was very simple.

Try this:

```sql
=MID(Fields!.Value,8,4)
```

Note: This worked for me because the value I was trying to get was a constant not sure it what you are trying to get is a constant as well.

Comment: `MID()` is not a TSQL function. You're presumably thinking of the Visual BASIC dialect available in Report Builder, but that's not what this is about.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been a while.. but here is an idea

```
declare @test varchar(25) = 'images/test.jpg'

select
 @test as column_name
 , parsename(replace(@test,'/','.'),1) as jpg
 ,parsename(replace(@test,'/','.'),2) as test
  ,parsename(replace(@test,'/','.'),3) as images
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [Royi Namir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859154/royi-namir)'s answer useful but expanded upon it to create it as a function. I renamed the variables to what made sense to me but you can translate them back easily enough, if desired.

Also, the code in Royi's answer already handled the case where the character being searched from does not exist (it starts from the beginning of the string), but I wanted to also handle cases where the character that is being searched to does not exist.

In that case it acts in a similar manner by starting from the searched from character and returning the rest of the characters to the end of the string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getValueBetweenTwoStrings](@inputString 
NVARCHAR(4000), @stringToSearchFrom NVARCHAR(4000), @stringToSearchTo 
NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN      
DECLARE @retVal NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @stringToSearchFromSearchPattern NVARCHAR(4000) = '%' + 
@stringToSearchFrom + '%'

SELECT @retVal = SUBSTRING (
       @inputString,
       PATINDEX(@stringToSearchFromSearchPattern, @inputString) + LEN(@stringToSearchFrom),
       (CASE
            CHARINDEX(
                @stringToSearchTo,
                @inputString,
                PATINDEX(@stringToSearchFromSearchPattern, @inputString) + LEN(@stringToSearchFrom))
        WHEN
            0
        THEN
            LEN(@inputString) + 1
        ELSE
            CHARINDEX(
                @stringToSearchTo,
                @inputString,
                PATINDEX(@stringToSearchFromSearchPattern, @inputString) + LEN(@stringToSearchFrom))
        END) - (PATINDEX(@stringToSearchFromSearchPattern, @inputString) + LEN(@stringToSearchFrom))
   )
RETURN @retVal
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.getValueBetweenTwoStrings('images/test.jpg','/','.') AS MyResult
```

Answer (score 1):

I got some invalid length errors. So i made this function, this should not give any length problems. Also when you do not find the searched text it will return a NULL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [FN].[SearchTextGetBetweenStartAndStop](@string varchar(max),@SearchStringToStart varchar(max),@SearchStringToStop varchar(max))

RETURNS varchar(max)

BEGIN


    SET @string =    CASE 
                         WHEN CHARINDEX(@SearchStringToStart,@string) = 0
                           OR CHARINDEX(@SearchStringToStop,RIGHT(@string,LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(@SearchStringToStart,@string) + 1 - LEN(@SearchStringToStart))) = 0
                         THEN NULL
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@string
                                       ,CHARINDEX(@SearchStringToStart,@string) + LEN(@SearchStringToStart) + 1
                                       ,(CHARINDEX(@SearchStringToStop,RIGHT(@string,LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(@SearchStringToStart,@string) + 1 - LEN(@SearchStringToStart)))-2)     
                                       )
                     END


    RETURN @string

END
```

Answer (score 1):

if Input= pg102a-wlc01s.png.intel.com and Output should be pg102a-wlc01s

we can use below query :

```
select Substring(pc.name,0,charindex('.',pc.name,0)),pc.name from tbl_name pc
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are more than one or none occurences of given character use this:

```
DECLARE @rightidx int = CASE
    WHEN 'images/images/test.jpg' IS NULL OR (CHARINDEX('.', 'images/images/test.jpg')) <= 0 THEN LEN('images/images/test.jpg')
    ELSE  (CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('images/images/test.jpg')) - 1)
END

SELECT RIGHT('images/images/test.jpg', @rightidx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query gives you data before '-'
Ex- W12345A-4S

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column_Name,0, CHARINDEX('-',Column_Name))  as 'new_name'
from [abc].
```

Output - W12345A

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Declare @test varchar(100)='images/test.jpg'
Select REPLACE(RIGHT(@test,charindex('/',reverse(@test))-1),'.jpg','')
```

Comment: Please try to explain your solution a little bit, and why it would work. In order to let more people benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the work of [Josien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249353/josien), I wondered about a simplification.

Would this also work? Much shorter:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX ('/', col) + 1, CHARINDEX ('.', col) - CHARINDEX ('/', col) - 1);
```

(I can't test right now because of right issues at my company SQL server, which is a problem in its own right)

Answer (score 0):

> Simply Try With LEFT ,RIGHT ,CHARINDEX

```
select 
LEFT((RIGHT(a.name,((CHARINDEX('/', name))+1))),((CHARINDEX('.', (RIGHT(a.name, 
                     ((CHARINDEX('/', name))+1)))))-1)) splitstring,
a.name      
from 
   (select 'images/test.jpg' as name)a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @searchStart nvarchar(100) = 'search ';
declare @searchEnd nvarchar(100) = ' ';
declare @string nvarchar(4000) = 'This is a string to search (hello) in this text ';

declare @startIndex int = CHARINDEX(@searchStart, @string,0) + LEN(@searchStart);
declare @endIndex int = CHARINDEX(@searchEnd, @string, @startIndex + 1);
declare @length int = @endIndex - @startIndex;
declare @sub nvarchar(4000) = SUBSTRING(@string, @startIndex, @length)

select @startIndex, @endIndex, @length, @sub
```

This is a little more legible than the one-liners in this answer which specifically answer the question, but not in a generic way that would benefit all readers.  This could easily be made into a function as well with a slight modification.

Answer (score 0):

This was the approach I took.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_text_before_char(@my_string nvarchar(255),@my_char char(1))
    RETURNS nvarchar(255)
    AS
        BEGIN;
            return IIF(@my_string LIKE '%' + @my_char + '%',left  (@my_string, IIF(charindex(@my_char, @my_string) - 1<1,1,charindex(@my_char, @my_string) - 1)),'');
        END;
    
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_text_after_char(@my_string nvarchar(255),@my_char char(1))
        RETURNS nvarchar(255)
    AS
    BEGIN;
       return IIF ( @my_string LIKE '%' + @my_char + '%' ,RIGHT ( @my_string , IIF ( charindex ( @my_char ,reverse(@my_string) )-1 < 1 ,1 ,charindex ( @my_char ,reverse(@my_string) )-1 ) ) , '' )
    END;
    
    SELECT
          dbo.get_text_before_char('foo-bar','-')
        , dbo.get_text_after_char('foo-bar','-')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @test varchar(100)='images/test.jpg'
select right(left(@test, charindex('.', @test) - 1),4)
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this script answers the question. This helps to provide context, and makes your answer much more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for the first part:

```
SELECT LEFT(@test, CASE CHARINDEX('/', @test)-1 WHEN -1 THEN LEN(@test) ELSE CHARINDEX('/', @test)-1 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I'm using snowflake and this worked fine for me:

```
substring(column_name, charindex('start pattern', column_name)+ start pattern length, charindex('end pattern', column_name)-charindex('start pattern', column_name)-start pattern lenght)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simply Query to arpoach it, This is clean Tydy and no long to run and understand

My string

```
B:\Pato\SubPAto\SUBUBPATO\El Patito Feo.prf
```

Result:

```
El Patito Feo
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT ScanFileName,    
    SUBSTRING(ScanFileName, LEN(ScanFileName) - CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(ScanFileName)) + 2, 
    CHARINDEX ('.', ScanFileName)-(LEN(ScanFileName) - CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(ScanFileName)) + 2)
    )
  FROM Table
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?