# sql server all characters to right of first hyphen

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2014, how can I extract all characters to the right of the first hyphen in a field where the first hyphen will have many combinations following it.

example 1:

> Aegean-1GB-7days-COMP

desired result:

> 1GB-7days-COMP

example 2:

> Aegean-SchooliesSpecial-7GB

desired result:

> SchooliesSpecial-7GB

example 3:

AkCityOaks-1Day-3GB

desired result:

1Day-3GB

Comment: So, what did you try? What platform do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010453/get-everything-after-and-before-certain-character-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4):

Using CHARINDEX AND SUBSTRING would work:

```
DECLARE @HTXT as nvarchar(max)
SET @HTXT='lkjhgf-wtrfghvbn-jk87fry--jk'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@HTXT, CHARINDEX('-', @HTXT) + 1, LEN(@HTXT))
```

Result:
wtrfghvbn-jk87fry--jk

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `CharIndex` and 'SubString' to get the desired result.

When you do this, you will get the location of the first hyphen starting from the first character.

```
CharIndex ('Aegean-1GB-7days-COMP', '-', 1)
```

Then cutting the string is easy

```
Select     
    SubString (
      'Aegean-1GB-7days-COMP', 
      CharIndex ('-', 'Aegean-1GB-7days-COMP', 1) + 1,
      Len('Aegean-1GB-7days-COMP') - CharIndex ('-', 'Aegean-1GB-7days-COMP', 1)
    )
```

Since your data is most likely in a column, I would change this to

```
Select     
    SubString (
      YourColumnName, 
      CharIndex ('-', YourColumnName, 1) + 1,
      Len(YourColumnName) - CharIndex ('-', YourColumnName, 1)
    )
From YourTableName
```

If you want to match `--` instead of `-`, then look at PatIndex`

[Read Here about CharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

[Read Here about PatIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

[Read Here about SubString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Comment: Only problem is when I plug into a view I get "function argument count error"

Comment: It appears that a three-argument CHARINDEX() function can  be entered into the SQL Pane of the View Designer.

Comment: Easy solution, write the view yourself instead of using that awful view designer. :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) like this:

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @StartPos int

SET @StartPos = PATINDEX('%-%',@Text) + 1

RETURN SUBSTRING(@Text,@StartPos,LEN(@Text)-@StartPos)
```

Or in one:

```
SUBSTRING([Text],PATINDEX('%A%',[Text]) + 1, LEN([Text]) - PATINDEX('%A%',[Text]) + 1)
```