# SQL server triming

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to format the licenseenum column in my table by removing everything starting the before space and also I would like to remove any character in licenseenum column starting after  '-' including '-'

For example:
current data in Licenseenum GA 350-0
What I'm trying to get 350

Here is my code

```
select Licenseenum, SUBSTRING (Licenseenum, 4, LEN(Licenseenum)-1)
from licensee
```

this results
350-0

How would I remove -0 from the results?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get everything after and before certain character in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010453/get-everything-after-and-before-certain-character-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code. Its working fine in SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @Licenseenum  varchar(max)
SET @Licenseenum  ='GA 350-0'

DECLARE @TempLicense VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @License VARCHAR(100)
IF (len(@Licenseenum ) - len(replace(@Licenseenum ,' ',''))>=1)
    SET @TempLicense = (SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@Licenseenum ),CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Licenseenum ), 1) - 1)))
ELSE
    SET @TempLicense = @Licenseenum 

SELECT  @License = (SELECT LEFT(@TempLicense,LEN(@TempLicense) - charindex('-',reverse(@TempLicense),1)))
SELECT @License AS Licenseenum
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Praveen, you've got the acceptance, nice for you... But could you please explain, why you are doing this so complicated with reversing back and forth and over and over again?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='GA 350-0';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@YourString,CHARINDEX(' ',@YourString,1),CHARINDEX('-',@YourString,1)-CHARINDEX(' ',@YourString,1));
```

### UPDATE 1

This is quite the same, but better to read

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='GA 350-0';

WITH Positions AS
(
    SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',@YourString,1) AS posBlank
          ,CHARINDEX('-',@YourString,1) AS posMinus  
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@YourString,posBlank,posMinus-posBlank)
FROM Positions;
```

### UPDATE 2 Avoid the leading blank...

My logic needs small correction in order to cut the blank before the number:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@YourString,posBlank+1,posMinus-posBlank-1)
```

Would be the same with the first example...

Comment: Your first query worked for me.Thank you and appreciated.