# SQL extracting text between characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I am trying to extract a string between two characters. The length could change for any of the numbers. The values I am trying to extract is only e.g. 0001A, 0002BB, 0003C etc.

Using `select SUBSTRING(ordtxt,7,4) as ordtxt`, I would be able to only extract x amount of characters from the left which isn't really something I am looking for.

```
100/0/0001A/001
101/000/0002BB/001
102/00/0003C/0001
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why do you want those numbers, but not 001, 00 or 102?

Comment: This [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010453/get-everything-after-and-before-certain-character-in-sql-server) might help

Comment: so you want the digits between the 2nd `/` and the 3rd `/`?

Comment: Hogan, correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a simple XML approach, which would isolate values from a delimited string

```
 SELECT
   convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(YourColumn,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')
 FROM YourTable
```

The solution breaks down the string into positions denoted by a numeric index, simply select the required element you need.

For example if you need 0001, 0002, 0003 then use a position of 3 in the function above.

The syntax is based on SQL Server

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use XML within Ms SQL

Comment: you just include it in the select statement

Comment: Thanks jimmy. I attempted your updated select statement but I do get an error for the equal sign Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: @V.Bach remove `YourColumn =`

Comment: oh this worked out great. Thanks for the help jimmy & forpas!