# Substring in middle of names

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table contain column [File] with names of files

I have files like :

U_1456789_**23456789**_File1_automaticrepair

U_3456789_**3456789**_File2_jumpjump

B_1134_**445673**_File3_plane

I_111345_**333345**_File4_chupapimonienio

P_1156_**3556**_File5 idk what

etc...

I want to create column where i will see only bolded values, how i can do that ?

Comment: Which RDBMS system are you using? Not all of them support regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports it, a regular expression is a much cleaner solution. If it doesn't, (and [SQL Server doesn't by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187489(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) you can use a combination of [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) and [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) to get the text in the column between the second and third underscores [as explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010453/get-everything-after-and-before-certain-character-in-sql-server).

Assuming a table created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Files] ([File] NVARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO [Files] VALUES 
('U_1456789_23456789_File1_automaticrepair'),
('U_3456789_3456789_File2_jumpjump'),
('B_1134_445673_File3_plane'),
('I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio'),
('P_1156_3556_File5 idk what');
```

You can use the query:

```
SELECT [File],
  SUBSTRING([File], 
            
            -- Start taking after the second underscore
            -- in the original field value
            CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1) + 1,  

            -- Continue taking for the length between the
            -- index of the second and third underscores
            CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1) + 1) - (CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1) + 1)) AS Part
FROM [Files];
```

To get the results:

| File | Part |
| --- | --- |
| U_1456789_23456789_File1_automaticrepair | 23456789 |
| U_3456789_3456789_File2_jumpjump | 3456789 |
| B_1134_445673_File3_plane | 445673 |
| I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio | 333345 |
| P_1156_3556_File5 idk what | 3556 |

[See the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1880/9)

---

**Edit**: to brute force support for inputs with only two underscores:

```
CREATE TABLE [Files] ([File] NVARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO [Files] VALUES 
('U_1456789_23456789_File1_automaticrepair'),
('U_3456789_3456789_File2_jumpjump'),
('B_1134_445673_File3_plane'),
('I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio'),
('P_1156_3556_File5 idk what'),
('K_25444_filenamecar');
```

Add a case for when a third underscore could not be found and adjust the start position/length passed to `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT [File],
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1) + 1) = 0
    THEN
      SUBSTRING([File],
                CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1,
                CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1) - (CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1))
    ELSE
      SUBSTRING([File], 
                CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1) + 1,  
                CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1) + 1) - (CHARINDEX('_', [File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) + 1) + 1))
    END AS Part
FROM [Files];
```

| File | Part |
| --- | --- |
| U_1456789_23456789_File1_automaticrepair | 23456789 |
| U_3456789_3456789_File2_jumpjump | 3456789 |
| B_1134_445673_File3_plane | 445673 |
| I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio | 333345 |
| P_1156_3556_File5 idk what | 3556 |
| K_25444_filenamecar | 25444 |

[See the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27741/4)

Note that this approach is even more brittle and you're definitely in the realm of problem that is likely better handled in application code instead of by the SQL engine.

Comment: Something is wrong,  when i select top 1000 that was working fine but when i select top 10000  it has error "Invalid lenght parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Comment: Do you have some values that don't have a second/third underscore? This is a brittle solution that assumes a given input pattern.

Comment: yes, i found only 5 and looks like K_25444_filenamecar

Comment: I added a section about falling back to the first/second underscore if the second/third don't exist. I would seriously consider a different approach unless this is a one-off solution.

Comment: thats fine everything, do you know maybe how i can cut chupapimonienio from  [I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio] and if  [K_25444_filenamecar] cut filenamecar ?

Comment: I tried 

right([File], len([File]) - 
   charindex('_', [File], 
      charindex('_', [File], 
         charindex('_', [File])  for I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio


and 
right([File], len([File]) - 
   charindex('_', [File], 
      charindex('_', [File] for K_25444_filenamecar
         

for

but idk how to make case

Comment: Sure, SqlFiddle is down right now so I can't show you a demo, but [here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024978/find-index-of-last-occurrence-of-a-sub-string-using-t-sql/20369450) about finding the last occurrence of a character in a field.

Comment: The answer suggests using [`REVERSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) then `CHARINDEX` to find the last occurrence in the string, then `SUBSTRING` from the [`LEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) minus the index you found to take everything after the last occurrence.

Comment: but how to make case here ?

Comment: I mean " I tried right([File], len([File]) - charindex('', [File], charindex('', [File], charindex('', [File]) for I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio and right([File], len([File]) - charindex('', [File], charindex('_', [File] for K_25444_filenamecar" this is fine but idk how can i add CASE here ...

Comment: You want the contents of the field after the last underscore, right? There's a better way than hardcoding cases for different numbers of underscores in the field. Ask another question including details about your data and the output you want if you need more details.

Comment: Yes i know but some files are like L_243434_33333_Super_Mountain_Landscape.png

Comment: I assume you'd want "Super_Mountain_Landscape" from that?

Comment: yes and that  "right([File], len([File]) - charindex('', [File], charindex('', [File], charindex('', [File])"  give me this

Comment: the problem is that not working for files like K_34343_Superauto ...

Comment: I don't have a good solution. If you know the input and desired output, you can of course write an expression that works for that one input and output. Choosing which expression to use for which input/output is more logic than just a `CASE` statement. I suspect you're going to need to do some manipulation in code after fetching results from SQL.

Comment: For example, you say that `I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio` should return `chupapimonienio` which could be done by taking everything after the last underscore. But that wouldn't work for `L_243434_33333_Super_Mountain_Landscape.png` where you want `Super_Mountain_Landscape`. A `CASE` statement won't help you until you figure out how to tell which rule to apply to which field. If you have a good set of input/expected output, a new question could help give you ideas.

Comment: not exactly  I_111345_333345_File4_chupapimonienio should return  File4_chupapimonienio everything is after third underscore

Comment: for files like l_33333_44444_file_chupapimonienio return everything after third underscore and for files like K_2137911_bus  return everything after second underscore

Comment: That's just the code in my answer without an ending `SUBSTRING` index. [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27741/8)

Comment: Yes i see and its everything working great :DDD, really big thanks for your help, you are amazing :)