# Hello All, I need to extract the first character before a '.' and then the rest

Tags: sql

It's a SQL instance and the examples are as follows:

Table values to transform:

String is Donald.Duck and the desired result is DDuck
String is Mickey.Mouse and the desired result is MMouse

Comment: tag with database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get everything after and before certain character in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010453/get-everything-after-and-before-certain-character-in-sql-server). Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more details. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression in sql.  it runs slower but it will use the dot.net framework

The regular expression is simple.  Look forward and find a period then capture all non space characters proceeding the period.

how to call a regular expression in tsql

https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-regex-commands-in-sql-server/

```
#extract the data to a csv then process it and update back into the database

txt="Donald.Duck and the desired result is DDuck String other strings are Mickey.Mouse and Daffy.Duck"

pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)')
result=re.findall(pattern,txt)
for item in result:
     front,back=item.split('.')
     txt=re.sub(item, front[0]+'.'+back,txt)

print(txt)
```

output

```
 Donald.Duck and the desired result is DDuck String other strings are Mickey.Mouse and Daffy.Duck
```

Sql steps:

1. split the words into a table of words by space
2. fetch each word and do an instr to check for a period
3. split the front and back word by period
4. keep the first character of the front word and reassemble and replace the phrase
5. join the words into a sentence and update the database with the new sentence.