# How to extract day, hour, and minute from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a column that contains values as below:

```
Duration
--------
minute45hour1day0
minute8hour10day2
minute15hour2day11
...
```

I want to extract day, hour, and minute to a different column:

```
day | hour | minutes
----+------+--------
 0  |  1   | 45
 2  | 10   |  8
11  |  2   | 15
```

To get the day I tired:

```
LEFT(StageDuration, CHARINDEX('day', Duration) - 1) AS day,
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get everything after and before certain character in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010453/get-everything-after-and-before-certain-character-in-sql-server)

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: 2012 R2 version

Comment: @Ibrennan208 your suggested answer is different than my question, in my case the number of minutes, hours and days can be 1 or two characters it's not static.
if you think there is a way around it, please add a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
SELECT
REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(REPLACE( REPLACE( replace('minute45hour1day0','minute',''),'hour' ,'.') , 'day','.')), 1)) AS minute ,
REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(REPLACE( REPLACE( replace('minute45hour1day0','minute',''),'hour' ,'.') , 'day','.')), 2)) AS hour ,
REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(REPLACE( REPLACE( replace('minute45hour1day0','minute',''),'hour' ,'.') , 'day','.')), 3)) AS day
```

---

Also please check for [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to undestand the Logic

REVERSE is simple. Ex: ali -> ila

Comment: Yes +1 . Available from 2014 and higher version.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code

```
declare @string Varchar(50) = 'minute45hour1day0'
--declare @string Varchar(50) = 'minute8hour10day2'
--declare @string Varchar(50) = 'minute15hour2day11'

select CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('minute',@string)>0 AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('minute',@string)+6,2))=1  
                  THEN SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('minute',@string)+6,2) 
                  ELSE SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('minute',@string)+6,1) 
            END AS [minutes]
     ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('hour',@string)>0 AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('hour',@string)+4,2))=1  
                  THEN SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('hour',@string)+4,2) 
                  ELSE SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('hour',@string)+4,1) 
            END AS [hour]
     ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('day',@string)>0 AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('day',@string)+3,3))=1  
                  THEN SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('day',@string)+3,2)
                  ELSE SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('day',@string)+3,1) 
            END AS [day]
```

You can change the logic to handle if the day count is more than 2 digits.

Comment: I do echo if you have sql server 14+ version

Answer (score 1):

I'd go a slightly different route to the other commenters and suggest creating a function that handles this logic, as it's something that you'll probably want to use in a few different queries will eventually and -- when you upgrade to newer versions of SQL Server -- have more efficient means of dealing with.

So, I'd create a function like:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DurationSplit(@Duration VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS @R TABLE ( [Days] INT, [Hours] INT, [Minutes] INT)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Days INT, @Hours INT, @Minutes INT;

    SET @Duration = REPLACE(@Duration, 'day', '.');
    SET @Duration = REPLACE(@Duration, 'hour', '|');
    SET @Duration = REPLACE(@Duration, 'minute', '');

    SET @Minutes = CAST(
        SUBSTRING(@Duration, 0, CHARINDEX('|', @Duration, 0))
    AS INT);
    SET @Duration = SUBSTRING(@Duration, CHARINDEX('|', @Duration, 0)+1, 50);
    SET @Hours = CAST(
        SUBSTRING(@Duration, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @Duration, 0))
    AS INT);
    SET @Duration = SUBSTRING(@Duration, CHARINDEX('.', @Duration, 0)+1, 50);
    SET @Days = CAST(@Duration AS INT);
    
    INSERT @R ([Days], [Hours], [Minutes])
        VALUES (@Days, @Hours, @Minutes);

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

which then you can include in your queries like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    Duration VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT #Data (Duration) VALUES ('minute45hour1day0'), ('minute8hour10day2'), ('minute15hour2day11');

SELECT * 
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY dbo.DurationSplit(d.Duration);
```